# Symbol present in .so, compiled .o references it but link fails

Tags: c++, static, linker

I have a strange problem linking c++ with Leptonica. Normal function invocation works fine, but I need functions from the library which were originally not exposed in the .so library. So I have searched for the two interesting functions in the source, removed the *static* keyword, so they look similar to exposed ones. I have remade the full library after a make clean. The .so file looks OK:

```
nm liblept.so.5.0.0
...
000000000009d010 T dewarpGetMeanVerticals
000000000009d160 T dewarpGetTextlineCenters
000000000009d8f0 T dewarpIsLineCoverageValid
```

Compiling to .o file and observing it:

```
g++ -c -std=c++11 -I../leptonica/src/src/ preproc.cpp -L../leptonica/src/.libs/ -llept -o preproc
nm preproc
...
U dewarpGetMeanVerticals
U dewarpIsLineCoverageValid
```

While the same compiling without -c flag results in

```
/tmp/ccCPqS1R.o: In function `_dewarpGetTextlineCenters(Pix*, int)':
preproc.cpp:(.text+0x3d5): undefined reference to `dewarpGetMeanVerticals'
/tmp/ccCPqS1R.o: In function `_dewarpBuildPageModel(L_Dewarp*, char const*)':
preproc.cpp:(.text+0x81d): undefined reference to `dewarpIsLineCoverageValid'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What do I do wrong?

Thank you in advance: Balázs

Comment: I notice that you're showing us what's in liblept.so.5.0.0 and linking against liblept.so.  Is it possible that you need to update a symbolic link so that you're linking against the correct .so file?

Comment: `nm` is not the best tool here, try `readelf --dyn-syms -W`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Have you made correct declarations of your newly-external functions visible to the client code?

Comment: Sorry for the post, I have found the problem: there was an old instance of the .so in /usr/local/lib which I forgot. Removing it fixed the problem. Thank Cleblanc for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

<s>I think you may need the extern "C" keywords around those functions if you want to expose them in the so.</s>  Since the names don't appear to be mangled by the C++ compiler in the .so this is probably not the case.

I notice that you're showing us what's in liblept.so.5.0.0 and linking against liblept.so. Is it possible that you need to update a symbolic link so that you're linking against the correct .so file?

Comment: On the other hand, symbols in app seem to be mangled (as otherwise linker wouldn't know their types). Maybe OP is missing extern "C" in application code?

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.